# Join two querys in one mysql

Tags: php, mysql, optimization

I have these two tables.

Table `INCOMES`

ID | VALIDATED | REVENUE | DATE

1         123                 12            2017-03-01
2         99                  44             2017-03-01
3         66                  44             2017-04-01
4         66                  44             2017-04-01
5         66                  44             2017-05-01

Table `COSTES`

ID | COSTS | DATE
1           123         2017-04-01
2           99           2017-04-01
3           77           2017-05-01
4           33           2017-05-01
5           66           2017-06-01

I need to get SUM(VALIDATED) [sum of a full month, for example 2017-03 is 123 + 99], SUM(REVENUE)[sum of a full month, for example 2017-03 is 12 + 44], SUM(COSTS)[sum of a full month, for example 2017-03 is 0 + 0, beucase there is no costs in that month] and DATE VALUES orderer by DATE. 
The result should be something like that:

RESULT QUERY
VALIDATED | REVENUE | COSTS | DATE
222                      56                 0         2017-03
132                      88                 22        2017-04
66                      44                   22        2017-05
0                          0                    66         2017-06
i have already that QUERY separated

```
SELECT
   SUM(validated) AS 'validated',
   SUM(revenue) AS 'revenue',
   DATE_FORMAT(Date, '%Y-%m') AS Date
FROM incomes WHERE date LIKE '%2017%'
GROUP BY(DATE_FORMAT(Date, '%Y-%m'));
```

---

```
SELECT
   SUM(validacion) AS 'costes',
   DATE_FORMAT(Date, '%Y-%m') AS Date
FROM costes WHERE date LIKE '%2017%'
GROUP BY(DATE_FORMAT(Date, '%Y-%m'));
```

please help will be appreciated.

Comment: do you mean to join those two queries by Date?

Comment: I don't see how you would join two tables without a reference between them. It is bound to break when there are two buys on the same date.

Comment: @Adder they share the month, thing is some months maybe there is no 'costs' so if there is no entrance for that months that should be 0. I explain that on the example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the UNION statment for this goal.

The SELECT call need to contain the same columns names. So the SGBD crates a temp table (that I called "union_tb") so you can play with it as you want.

Take a Look:

```
SELECT SUM(union_tb.validated) AS validated
, SUM(union_tb.revenue) AS revenue
, SUM(union_tb.costes) AS costes
, union_tb.date

FROM (

        SELECT SUM(validated) AS 'validated'
        , 0 AS 'costes'
        ,  SUM(revenue) AS 'revenue'
        , DATE_FORMAT(DATE, '%Y-%m') AS 'date'

            FROM incomes
            WHERE YEAR(DATE) = 2017
            GROUP BY(DATE_FORMAT(DATE, '%Y-%m'))

    UNION

        SELECT 0 AS 'validated'
        ,  SUM(validacion) AS 'costes'
        , 0 AS 'revenue'
        ,  DATE_FORMAT(DATE, '%Y-%m') AS 'date'

        FROM costes
        WHERE YEAR(DATE) = 2017
        GROUP BY(DATE_FORMAT(DATE, '%Y-%m'))
) AS union_tb 

WHERE 1 
GROUP BY union_tb.date ;
```

Comment: i'll try, and give feedback. give a second.

Comment: If in particular month,there is no entry for both the table,Then did your answer gives count 0 for both value?

Comment: If a particular month has not entryies in  both tables, this month will not appear in result set. #Tip: For 'date' datatypes you should use date functions: YEAR(date_colum) = 2017 instead 'LIKE'. And please check the code correction I did ('0' AS 'costes' -> 0 AS 'costes' [no single quotes]).

Comment: @RenatoTarso perfect, i've checked and works perfectly. thanks for that

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    SUM(validated) AS 'validated',
    SUM(revenue) AS 'revenue',
    SUM(COS.COSTS) COSTS,
    DATE_FORMAT(Date, '%Y-%m') AS Date
FROM
    incomes INC
        INNER JOIN
    costes COS ON DATE_FORMAT(INC.Date, '%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(COS.Date, '%Y-%m')
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(INC.Date, '%Y-%m')
```

Try above query.

Comment: thing is with that query i only get values where the month exist on both tables. In the example table COSTES do not have month 03, but INCOMES do have. So for that month the value on costs should be 0.